# Dynamically assign object properties and values in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, dynamicobject

Help me to create single object with dynamic properties.

For example:
Suppose we are getting the following object from database,

```
var obj=[ 
{"name":"John", "age":35}, 
{"name":"Greesham", "age":37},
{"name":"Raman","age":42},
{"name":"Krish", "age":30}];
```

Now we want to create an object with above object values as keys/properties in c# class.

Expected Result:

```
var obj2=new{ John=35, Greesham=37, Raman=42, Krish=30 };
```

[Note: Here i can use IDictionary but i want only one object, to pass templater plugin to print in word document]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what seems to be the problem?

Comment: You can use the `dynamic` keyword.  But why you would want an object like that, I don't know.  Seems like an XY problem

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of such a dynamic object? What problem are you trying to solve like this?

Comment: It seems like using a `dictionary` would save you a lot of trouble here

Comment: It looks like you want a `Dictionary<string,int>` with name as key and age as value

Comment: _[Note: Here i can use IDictionary but i want only one object, to pass templater plugin to print in word document]_ The plugin is your own? If so, yo can adapt, if not, what type does it expect?

Comment: You can also use ExpandoObject if you are set on setting properties on the go. There are several possibilities with trade offs.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Magnetron We have a nuget package "templater" used for print data in word file, it accepts one object with properties,

Comment: C# also has the `dynamic` variables and the `ExpandoObject`. You can add anything to them and retrieve them again but it's not strong typed. Use them sparingly.

Comment: What do you expect when two people have the same name?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Dictionary<string, int> obj2 = JArray.Parse(obj)
                                   .ToDictionary(
                                   ja => (string)ja["name"],
                                   ja => (int) ja["age"]
                                   );
```

but if you want complitely independent from property names

```
Dictionary<string, object> obj2 = JArray.Parse(obj)
                                 .ToDictionary(
                                 ja => (string)((JObject)ja).Properties().ToArray()[0].Value,
                                 ja => (object) ((JObject)ja).Properties().ToArray()[1].Value
                                 );
```